# How to get which cluster has fetched the request. PM2 clusters

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

How can i get the pm2 cluster information which fetched my request.
I have tried using `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: This is lite on info ... but perhaps a unique ID each cluster generates when it is started?

Comment: Yes i see the unique id on my log screen... But how to fetch that id in code. @Wainage